# 3D bump function with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a 3D bump function with tikzpicture. The handmade idea is:

[image]

Now the best I got is:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (z) at (0,4);
    \coordinate (y) at (7,0);
    \coordinate (x) at (-1,-1);
    \draw[->] (-1,0)--(7,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5)--(0,4);
    \draw[->] (0.3,0.3)--(-1,-1);
    \draw (y) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw (x) node[left] {$x$};
    \draw (z) node[left] {$z$};
    
    \draw[thick,scale=1.3, domain=-0.05:3.05, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {exp(-(\x-2)*(\x*2-2)+0.1)-0.5});
    \draw[fill=blue, opacity=0.3, thick,scale=1.3, domain=0:3, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {exp(-(\x-2)*(\x*2-2)+0.1)-0.5});
    \draw [fill=blue, opacity=0.3, blue] (-0.05,-0.6235) arc (180:360:2 and 0.3) ;
    \draw [opacity=0.4,blue,dashed] (-0.05,-0.64) arc (170:10:2 and 0.2) ;
    \draw [opacity=0.4,blue] (1.53,1.3) arc (180:360:0.42 and 0.13) ;
    \draw [dashed ,opacity=0.4,blue] (1.53,1.3) arc (180:0:0.42 and 0.1) ;
    \draw [opacity=0.4,blue] (1.1,0.3) arc (180:360:0.85 and 0.14) ;
    \draw [dashed,opacity=0.4,blue] (1.1,0.3) arc (180:0:0.85 and 0.14) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can you help me to get a drawing more similar to the handmade drawing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like you should use something properly 3D and export it to TikZ. Computing the range for dotted/continuous curve is going to be a huge problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g. PGFPlots

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={100}{30},
xmin=-1, xmax=6,
ymin=-1, ymax=6,
zmin=-1, zmax=4,
xlabel={x}, ylabel={y}, zlabel={z},
axis lines=center,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot3[
surf, colormap/viridis, faceted color=gray,
opacity=0.5,
domain=1:5, y domain=1:5,
samples=20, samples y=20,
line join=round,
] {2*exp(-(\x-3)^2-(\y-3)^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bell shaped 3D surface]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={100}{30},
xmin=-1, xmax=6,
ymin=-1, ymax=6,
zmin=-1, zmax=4,
xlabel={x}, ylabel={y}, zlabel={z},
axis lines=center,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot3[
surf, colormap/viridis, faceted color=gray,
opacity=0.5,
domain=0:360, domain y=0:2,
samples=10, samples y=20,
line join=round,
] ( {y*cos(x)+3} , {y*sin(x)+3} , {2*exp(-(y*cos(x))^2-(y*sin(x))^2)} );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bell shaped 3D surface with polygon base]

Edit: only TikZ

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]
\draw[->] (-1,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[above]{x};
\draw[->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,5,0) node[above]{y};
\draw[->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{z};
\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
\fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)+3} , {2*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(120)+3} , {\t*sin(120)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(120))^2-(\t*sin(120))^2)} );
\end{scope}
\foreach \ang in {0,40,...,320}
  \draw[gray, thick] plot[domain=0:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+3} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\foreach \t in {0,0.3,...,2}
  \draw[gray, thick] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+3} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue bell shaped mesh]

Comment: i like this idea, but the philosophy and the intension was to use just tikzpicture.

Comment: the edit is very very close to the solution. do tou think the surface can be filled with a transparent colour?

Comment: the underlying idea is to create a sequence of transparent bumps moving in a certain direction

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to hpekristiansen I was able to create a sequence of transparent bumps:

[image]

```
\[ \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(120)} , {\t*sin(120)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(120))^2-(\t*sin(120))^2)} );
\end{scope} 

    \draw[->] (-1,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[above]{x};
\draw[->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,5,0) node[above]{y};
\draw[->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{z};
    
    \foreach \ang in {-80,-50,...,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \foreach \ang in {130,150,...,270}
\draw[black,dashed,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \foreach \t in {0,0.4,...,2}
\draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-90:130, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\foreach \t in {0,0.4,...,2}
\draw[black,dashed,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=130:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.3]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)+3} , {2*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(120)+3} , {\t*sin(120)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(120))^2-(\t*sin(120))^2)} );
\end{scope} 

\draw[->] (-1,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[above]{x};
\draw[->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,5,0) node[above]{y};
\draw[->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{z};

\foreach \ang in {-80,-50,...,130}
\draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+3} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

\foreach \ang in {130,150,...,270}
\draw[black,dashed,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+3} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

\foreach \t in {0,0.4,...,2}
\draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-90:130, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+3} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\foreach \t in {0,0.4,...,2}
\draw[black,dashed,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=130:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+3} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.1]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)+6} , {2*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(120)+6} , {\t*sin(120)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(120))^2-(\t*sin(120))^2)} );
\end{scope} 

\draw[->] (-1,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[above]{x};
\draw[->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,5,0) node[above]{y};
\draw[->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{z};

\foreach \ang in {-80,-50,...,130}
\draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+6} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

\foreach \ang in {130,150,...,270}
\draw[black,dashed,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:2, samples=10, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+6} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

\foreach \t in {0,0.4,...,2}
\draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-90:130, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+6} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\foreach \t in {0,0.4,...,2}
\draw[black,dashed,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=130:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)+6} , {\t*sin(\ang)+3} , {2*exp(-(\t*cos(\ang))^2-(\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );


\end{tikzpicture} \]
```

so it was possible for me to create a 3D drawing of the 2D drawing:

[image]

Comment: it can be refined in the sense that the axes are not in the background and the opacity is not that good

Comment: If you post complete code(compilable), others can see and test your findings. -I guess it is not important here. If you draw the axis as the very first and ONLY once, they will be in the background. It does not make sense to put your figure inside a formula `\[ .... \]`!